# How to add Navigation dependency to 7.x version of Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I created a new project due to a problem with an existing project.

I'm trying to add a dependency to a new project, but it's different from the gradle I've been doing so far.

I also went to the developer documentation, but it doesn't seem to have been updated for the new gradle yet.

Fortunately the app level gradle seems to be the same.

---

**Previous gradle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
    def nav_version = "2.4.2"

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // safe args
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // Dagger Hilt
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Current gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your dependencies above `plugins` block:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.2"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I don't need to touch `settings.gradle`?

Answer (score 2):

You can add Navigation plugin to your Project Gradle like this:

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.5.2' apply false
```

Comment: thanks By the way, you may add other dependencies in the future, what are the criteria for writing the code? It's not even listed in the official documentation.